# TYPO3 and GraphicsMagick not working properly

Tags: php, server, typo3, graphicsmagick

I have a Problem with the Graphicsmagick and TYPO3.

This is my current configuration:

- GraphicsMagick enabled: 1
- GraphicsMagick path: /usr/bin/ (1.3.20)
- GraphicsMagick path/LZW: /usr/bin/ (6.7.2-7)
- Version 5/GraphicsMagick flag: gm
- GDLib enabled: 1
- GDLib using PNG: 1
- IM5 effects enabled: -1 (Blurring/Sharpening with IM 5+)
- Freetype DPI: 72 (Should be 96 for Freetype 2)
- Mask invert: 0 (Should be set for some IM versions approx. 5.4+)
- File Formats: gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai

If I do the tests I get several errors at the following:

1. READ PNG, PDF, AI
2. WRITING PNG
3. SCALING AND COMBINING IS NOT WORKING AT ALL

I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: Is graphicsMagick correctly installed and available in the given path?

Comment: yes..the hoster installed it today morning and at the basic configurations in the install tool is graphicsmagick showing correctly. I have also cleared all caches and everything.
The thumbs at the content elements with images are shown but not more.

Comment: Please include these errors you are getting. Also it might be helpful to check with your hosting company, maybe they will know why they are showing. You can see what command is being run under each test, so you can ask your hosting company to check that. Also it is strange that the thumbs work, when TYPO3 cannot write png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your configuration:

1. It seems you are using two different libraries: GM 1.3.20 and IM 6.7.2-7, as your GM is not capable of doing LZW compression.

   Set the "version5/gm flag" to "im6" to make sure you only use one and try again; in general, mixing IM/GM might be problematic.
2. Reading PDF and AI requires GhostScript to be installed. If you don’t see any images there, this might be the reason.
3. It might be necessary to set the Freetype DPI to 96, at least it is required on all my installations on recent PHP versions.
4. You should set the "IM5 effects" to "1" if you need any of the advanced text image generation features; otherwise, generating text will not work or the generation results will look ugly, depending on what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks! Now it works. As you have written in your message the problem was mixing im/GM.